# Understanding the semantics of flatten

Tags: functional-programming, flatten

Most textbooks describe `flatMap` as a composition of `flatten` and `map`. While it is not so hard to understand `map`,  things become less clear (to me) when it comes to the semantics of `flatten`. In particular, I do not understand why it is possible to flatten List(Option(3)), whereas it is not possible to do the same on Option(List(3)). Can someone clarify?

```
scala> List(Option(3)).flatten
res9: List[Int] = List(3)

scala> Option(List(3)).flatten
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< Option[B].
       Option(List(3)).flatten
                       ^
```

Comment: Flattening sequences works with any iterable. On the other hand, what would you expect `Option(List(3,4))` to flatten to?

Comment: I think for understanding `flatMap`, you will only need to consider the `flatten` case where the two same types are nested.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean flatten should be understood as a function of type M[M[A]]->M[A]?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. (And for some types, such as lists, it is more general, but that's the exception from the rule)

Comment: It seems however M[M[A]]->M[A] is only part of the story about flatten...

Comment: @Bergi Interestingly, the other way around `List(Option(Num))` you actually could flatten the computational layers. However, this operation seems to be specific to this particular composition, that is there seems to be no way to generalize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<:<` in`List[Int] <:< Option[B]` means "is an approximate subtype."  `flatten` requires that the type on the inside be convertible to the type on the outside.  For `Lists` and `Options`, this conversion can only go one way.  An `Option(3)` can be converted to a `List(3)`, but a `List(1,2,3,4)` can't be converted to an `Option(1,2,3,4)`, because `Options` can hold at most one item.

Comment: It could however be converted to `Option(1)`? I guess that these conversions should only be implicit if they're lossless, though.

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if you had more than one item in the List in the second option?... There's no implicit conversion from Iterable (such as a List) to Option because during compile time there's no way to ensure an Iterable has one or cero items, it could have more and so, impossible to transform into an Option. That's the philosophy behind it.

The mechanisms behind it are `implicit`s, the class `<:<[A,B]` (Yes, it's a class, with the name `<:<` and can be sugared to `A <:< B`), and an implicit method that goes from Option to Iterable.

So the thing with the method `flatten` is that it expects an implicit of type (in your case) `<:<[List[Int],Option[Int]]` or `<:<[Option[Int],List[Int]]`.

There's only one definition of that class, and it works only for `<:<[A,A]`. That way the compile only can find evidence when you're using the same class, not this case. But if before, the Option is converted to Traversable, then the compiler can find an evidence
`<:<[Traversable[Int],Traversable[Int]]`... And such implicit conversion exists for `Option`, and a `List` is already a Traversable.
in this case there's an implicit conversion from `Option[A]` to `Traversable[A]` and so the compiler uses it and the finds the class `<:<`... Hope it was clear!

Just in case, check [this line of Scala's sourcecode](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/84112e8029d088674b957a23672510446c252969/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L500).